# Is there an operad whose algebras are homotopy commutative $E_1$-algebras?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

I might guess that the Boardman-Vogt tensor product of the $E_1$ operad and the $A_2$ operad might do the trick. That is, I would guess that an $A_2$ object in $E_1$ algebras, or equivalently an $E_1$ algebra in $H$-spaces, is the same as a homotopy commutative $E_1$ algebra. The idea would be to use the Eckmann-Hilton argument. But I'm not sure.

Comment: The simplest answer would be $E_2$, but that has a bit more structure than just "homotopy commutative". You could artificially build it by starting with the associative operad and adjoining a single operation giving the $\cup_1$ product.

Comment: Right, I'm specifically interested in _not_ using the $E_2$ operad because, as you say, it has more structure. I suppose you're right that it's clear I can do this with a free construction.

Comment: Since the standard $E_2$ operad (brace operad) is already cofibrant, you should be able to take the suboperad generated by $E_1$ and $\cup_1$.

Comment: I am biased toward algebra, so I didn't read your question carefully enough. It seems to me with enough assumptions on the unit you can do the Eckmann-Hilton argument and get the result you want. It would be interesting to make that operad in spaces and see that in chains you get the operad I described above, which on the surface seems much simpler.